# How i fix this Unable to import 'django.urls' error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Errors are:
1. No name 'urls' in module 'django'pylint(no-name-in-module)
Unable to import 'django.urls'
2. No name 'test' in module 'django'pylint(no-name-in-module)
Unable to import 'django.test'pylint(import-error)
3. No name 'http' in module 'django'pylint(no-name-in-module)
Unable to import 'django.http'pylint(import-error)

When I start the server the terminal shows me this -

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aviba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\aviba\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aviba\djangoproject\firsttry\firsttry\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('',include('firstapp.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\aviba\djangoproject\firsttry\firstapp\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\aviba\djangoproject\firsttry\firstapp\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.http import httpresponse
ImportError: cannot import name 'httpresponse' from 'django.http' (C:\Users\aviba\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py)
```

urls.py of the app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpattarns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
]
```

views.py of the app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import httpresponse

def home(request):
    return httpresponse("Hello Django")
```

urls.py of the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('firstapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

modules in python are case sensitive, it's `HttpResponse` not `httpresponse`

Comment: All [names/identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) in python are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try this as **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django")
```

Here httpresponse is case sensitive and hence we use it this way.
Read this it might help you [more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Python3 as interpreter. I had the same issue (using Django 3.1.2) and after selecting the right interpreter (python 3.7.8) it was fixed.